# Android DialogFlow V2 SDK Java Client Library Grpc Google Cloud Platform to Detect Intent from Live Audio Stream

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, grpc-java

How to create a new Android application with Dialogflow V2. What is a client library and how is it used it Android. I want to send a Stream to detect intent. How is it different from legacy SDK. Is there any sample Android code available anywhere?

How to implement the new V2 Java client library with Grpc communication in an Android app?

Which of the following shall i use & how with an Android APP?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-dialogflow

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 2):

This [Dialogflow](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) library works perfectly fine with my Android project and V2 Dialogflow agent. Code samples are there in the [documentation](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/blob/master/docs/integration.md). You can send text, voice, parameters and receive response, contexts, parameters, identified intents from it.

**Update**

If you are still looking to integrate Dialogflow into an Android project, take a look into my library. It will help you easily integrate a chatbot with complete UI in your app
https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-dialogflow-chatbot-library-6b7b3822e7bc

Comment: This approach is using Legacy Sdk & Dialogflow V2 api,  i want to implement the new V2 Jaba Client library using Google Cloud and directly send a voice stream doing Grpc communication

Comment: Not used the other way. You can check the Dialogflow GitHub for the repository that you may need.  https://github.com/dialogflow

Comment: @SreejithKMenon did you get anything :) if so, pls help?

Comment: @AfinasEM no i did not :(